Socket error 10013 when sending http request on localhost
I have this setup (stack of apps communicating over HTTP) on a single server:
IIS ARR proxy running on port 443 (open to world) -->
localhost:6101 (service A: dotnet 6 windows service listening on port 6101 using Kestrel) -->
IIS ARR proxy running on port 6200 (accepts only local traffic) -->
localhost:6201 (service B: another dotnet 6 windows service listening on port 6201 using Kestrel)
Occasionally (around once a day, but also it can be once an hour or once every few days) at random times the first IIS proxy responds with 502.3 errors. This happens when service A sends an HTTP request to localhost:6200/some_endpoint. Service A cannot communicate with localhost:6200 and reports the following exception:
2024-08-29 06:09:59,694 [116] ERROR 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (127.0.0.1:6200)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendCoreAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Polly.Timeout.AsyncTimeoutEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`2 timeoutProvider, TimeoutStrategy timeoutStrategy, Func`5 onTimeoutAsync, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.Timeout.AsyncTimeoutEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`2 timeoutProvider, TimeoutStrategy timeoutStrategy, Func`5 onTimeoutAsync, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy`1.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   ...

Then things get back to normal after 3-10 minutes. I can confirm the app listening on 6201 is still running fine and reports no errors. There is a lot of information out there about this error when creating a TcpListener or starting a Kestrel server on a reserved port, but I could not find any useful info about this error when it occurs intermittently when sending a HTTP request to an existing listener.
The question: what could be the underlying cause of such an error and how can I fix it?

It could be your firewall or antivirus that is blocking it.  As this is only intermittent issue, then it could be that it only occurs when the firewall/AV is busy, so it can't respond in time and blocks by default.  So check your settings to allow traffic on these ports.

Thanks @jason.kaisersmith I haven't thought about that due to random nature of things. It looks like it is my antivirus. Trying to adjust configuration now. Thanks again!

Please confirm that you are not being blocked by antivirus software or firewall. When sending http request, you can use TCPView to see if other process is using this port.

Based on @jason.kaisersmith comment I managed to pinpoint the problem - my antivirus was randomly blocking some requests on localhost (detecting them as threats). Solution: add exclusion rule or disable antivirus network monitor.
